# Wolfenstein 3D is now available for free online. But is this version any different than the original?

Tags: wolfenstein-3d

To celebrate the 20th anniversary of the game's release, Bethesda (which bought iD Software) was hosting a free in-browser version of Wolfenstein 3D. But I'm curious if this version is the exact version that was released in 1992. Are there any major gameplay changes? Are the graphics different? How about easter eggs?

Comment: After a first try, it look faithful to my memories.

Comment: I imagine that if they wanted to be less faithful, they could've enabled modern-style WASD moving and a mouse control that's not as awkward.

Comment: Not available to German IPs. Because of the swastikas. Arrgggh

Comment: argh, mein layben!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original Wolfenstein had six episodes to play.  The browser version only has 3.

Episode Select screen for Browser Version:

[image: Browser]

Episode Select screen for the original:

[image: Original]

<sub>[(Image Source)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdcnQISuF_Y)</sub>

Essentially, the browser version is only half of the original, with all other aspects appearing to be the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: If I remember right, the first version of this game was episodes 1-3 and 4-6 was something you bought separately.

Comment: @StevenBurnap They were part of the Nocturnal Missions expansion, although the Wolfenstein wiki says they were included in boxed copies after Nocturnal Missions was released.

Answer (score 30):

I passed countless hours on this game 20 year ago and, apart of some change in the *READ THIS!* section, I did not notice any changes to the gameplay and graphics. I did not remember the music because I did not have a Sound-Blaster card back then. (Hello PC speaker sounds.)

Along with the release of this browser port there is a [Wolfenstein 3D Director's Commentary with John Carmack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amDtAPHH-zE). As specified in the beginning of this video, you can watch John Carmack playing some levels on the **original DOS version**. A comparison of this video and the game reveals that the browser port seems faithful to the original.

Comment: +1 Agreed, my ingrained memories took over on the first level as I popped all the secrets and listened to the authentic nazi shouting!

Comment: Mein Leben! The first episode was the very first game I beat without cheat codes. It was where I learned the phrase "Guten tag!" - which I can't really say normally without some effort.

Comment: man, how much did you used to wish you had a Sound-Blaster card!

Comment: There was some remarkable creative use of PC speakers, how amazing was Star Control's digitized sound.

Comment: @invert I still think SC2 has some of the best music around, even on the built in PC speaker.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost the exact replica, it was one of the only games I did play, but let me see it seems it lacks the [LIM cheat code](http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D/codes)¹. Thanks to the cheat I did not have to disassemble the code for a God mode.

<sup>¹ LIM cheat code - Pressing L, I, and M simultaneously at any time during gameplay wil give you 100% health, 99 ammo, all weapons, and both keys (even if there are no keys in your current level). However, doing this will also reset your score to 0, and you will not be eligible for the high score list.</sup>

Comment: One of the first things I checked for too :)

Comment: The part of the code that sets the different debug flags is commented out in `game.js` (line 1236-1293). All interesting variables like ammo, weapon, score, health etc is stored in an object called `currentGame`. Unfortunately this object is stored in an internal variable in object `Wolf.Game` and I haven't found any external references so at first look it seams impossible to manipulate the flags. However, if you use Google Chrome and set a breakpoint at row 503 in `game.js` you could modify `Local.player.flags` to 16 (FL_GODMODE) and you become invincible! While you at it, set ammo to 10000!